How to select hardcoded CSS class with Vanilla Extract?
I’m migrating from Emotion to Vanilla Extract. I have a component which contains a third-party UI library component. This third-party component has a hardcoded class .ClassWhichICannotChange.
In Emotion I customized this component, like this.
//In Emotion
export const button = css({
    backgroundColor: "#green",
    "& .ClassWhichICannotChange": {
        padding: 6,
    },
});

In Vanilla Extract I tried the same, but got the error:
//In Vanilla Extract
export const button = style({
    backgroundColor: "green",
    "& .ClassWhichICannotChange": {
        padding: 6,
    },
});
//Error - Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"& .ClassWhichICannotChange"' 
//does not exist in type 'ComplexStyleRule'.ts(2353)

Any suggestions how to select hardcoded class in Vanilla Extract?
PS - here is an HTML for better understanding:
<MyComponent className={button}>
   <ThirdPartyLibraryComponent /> //this component has an inner CSS class .ClassWhichICannotChange
</MyComponent>


If I understand correctly, you're just trying to specify style for your button, when it also has ClassWhichICannotChange css class?

My component has a "button" CSS class. Inside of my component there is child - a library UI component with "ClassWhichICannotChange" class. I want to apply style to it

Here is the correct way to select hardcoded class in Vanilla Extract
import { style, globalStyle } from "@vanilla-extract/css";

export const button = style({
    backgroundColor: "green",
});

globalStyle(`${button} .ClassWhichICannotChange`, {
    padding: 6,
});


Selectors can be used to select hardcoded CSS class as well, but only if this class belongs to the same element. Vanilla Extract doesn't allow you to select a child element using selectors.

Or you could also use selectors selectors within your button styles
